# Is a structure declaration a declaration in the core language or the module language?

Tags: sml, ml

In [SML's grammar](https://people.mpi-sws.org/%7Erossberg/sml.html)

> **Core Language**
>
> ```
> dec ::=   val ⟨var⟩(,) valbind value
>           fun ⟨var⟩(,) funbind function
>           type typbind type
>           datatype datbind ⟨withtype typbind⟩ data type
>           datatype id = datatype longid data type replication
>           abstype datbind ⟨withtype typbind⟩ with dec end abstract type
>           exception exnbind exception
>           structure strbind structure (not allowed inside expressions)
>           empty
> ```
>
> **Module Language**
>
> Programs
>
> ```
> prog ::=   dec core declaration
>            functor fctbind functor declaration
>            signature sigbind signature declaration
>            empty
>            prog1 ⟨;⟩ prog2 sequence
>
> fctbind ::= id1 ( id2 : sig ) ⟨:⟨>⟩ sig⟩ = str ⟨and fctbind⟩    plain
> id ( spec ) ⟨:⟨>⟩ sig⟩ = str ⟨and fctbind⟩ opened
> sigbind    ::= id = sig ⟨and sigbind⟩ signature
> ```

Are structure, signature and functor all concepts in the module language, not in the core language?

I was wondering why does a structure declaration `structure strbind`  enter a program as a declaration `dec` through the core language, instead of the module language?

In other words, why is a structure declaration `structure strbind` classified as a declaration `dec` in the core language, instead of the module language, unlike signature declarations `signature sigbind` and functor declarations `functor fctbind`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Structure declarations are part of the module system. But they are allowed inside structure expressions, unlike functor and signature declarations. None of them is allowed inside the core level.

Technically, there are three levels of declarations in the actual language specification: core dec, structure dec, toplevel dec. The grammar you're looking at simplifies that a little, to avoid too much duplication.